# How to blur(css) div without blur child element (and without absolute)

Tags: html, css, blur

```css
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('images/zwemmen.png');
  height: 501px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
}

.opacity {
  background-color: rgba(5, 98, 127, 0.9);
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
  float: left;
  margin: 100px 0px 0px 30px;
  width: 410px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="opacity">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="images/zwemmen.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      a div wih all sort of information
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I do not want to blur the button, what do I need to do?

I would like to solve the problem without resorting to absolute positioning

Comment: Does this idea help: http://codepen.io/Dzomba/pen/npdfh (ie can you put the unblur on the child element)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L8ksa46g/5/ if button mustn't be a child element.... maybe something like this? p.s. button is inside row, but outside .col-lg-3?

Comment: @TarynEast good, can i use instead of .blur:hover another selector?

Comment: @nevermind, now button in div, and i am not sure what i am change include

Comment: You can always use another selector... rather than asking - why don't you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: @TarynEast may be i do anything wrong, becouse nothing to do

Comment: Already been answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406478/remove-blur-effect-on-child-element

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20039965/2236219. There is no other option of doing it without position and without making children.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azXWPN

Comment: have you considered looking into the experimental feature backdrop filter?
it applies a filter to everything behind an element.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> How to disable blur on child element?

```css
.enableBlur>* {
  filter: blur(1.2px);
}

.disableBlur {
  filter: blur(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="enableBlur">
  <hr>
  qqqqq<br>
  <span>qqqqq</span><br>
  <hr  class="disableBlur">
  <div>aaaaa</div>
  <div>bbbbb</div>
  <div class="disableBlur">DDDDD</div>
  <hr>
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n8FG4f09-ug/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACmA/ldtxmWX1SyY/photo.jpg?sz=48">
  <img class="disableBlur" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-n8FG4f09-ug/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACmA/ldtxmWX1SyY/photo.jpg?sz=48">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing the `>*` part which is key: apply blur to the children individually rather than to the parent, that way children can individually un-blur.

Comment: Is this a bug or I'm making a mistake? I do `.parent { filter: blur(1px); }` and then `.parent > * { filter: blur(0); }` but children are still blurred. Even the computed styles in the dev tools says they are blur(0), but they are still visually blurred (on Chrome).

Comment: today, i checked this code snippet, it still works. last chrome

Comment: This is brilliant, although the `disableBlur` class only seems to be effective on direct children. Put `<div class="disableBlur">DDDDD</div>` inside another div and it stays blurred. I have yet to find a way un-blur a grandchild.

Answer (score 76):

When using the `blur` or `opacity` property, it is not possible to ignore the child element. If you apply either of those properties to parent element, it will automatically apply to child elements too.

There is an alternate solution: create two elements inside your parent `div` – one `div` for the background and another `div` for the contents. Set `position:relative` on the parent `div` and set `position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; left:0px;` (or set height/width to 100%) to the child element for the background. Using this method, the content `div` will not be affected by properties on the background.

Example:

```css
#parent_div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  filter: blur(3px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent_div">
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="textarea">My Text</div>
</div>
```

If you see the background masking over the content, then use [the `z-index` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to send the background behind the second content `div`.

Comment: Great solution to a silly problem. Why can't you just override `filter` on children - not sure I understand why this property breaks CSS inheritance rules

Answer (score 12):

My solution seems a bit simpler but may have some compatibility issues. I just used [backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) with the blur filter.

```
backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
```

Comment: Only works for rather new browsers,  FF >=70, otherwise good idea!

Comment: Should be OK for most applications as of Oct 2022 (see [can i use](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter))

Answer (score 6):

Just create two divisions and adjust their z-indexes and margins such that the division you want to blur lies below the division you want to appear on top.

PS: Don't create division inside a division cause the child inherits the  parent's properties.

```css
#forblur {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px) -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  z-index: -1;
}

#on-top-container {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -200px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="forblur">
</div>
<div id="on-top-container">
  <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```