# Responsive image and blurred effect issue

Tags: html, css

## First issue

I have photo gallery on my page. If you click on photo you can see larger preview. Because I need to deal with mobile phones so I set:

```
.overview img {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

But I have problem. `img` height exceeds height of `.overview`.I need to cut off ends of `img` or some other way to solve problem.

## PEN - http://codepen.io/marekkobida/pen/yOPeXO

HTML:

```
<div class="dark" id="photo-gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>A</h1>

    <p>B</p>

    <div class="photos">
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
      <div class="photo"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="overview">
      <img src="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 8rem 1.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 65rem) {
  .container {
    width: 60rem;
  }
}

#photo-gallery {
  position: relative;
}

#photo-gallery .photos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -0.625rem;
  margin-top: 0.625rem;
}

#photo-gallery .photos > div {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 0 0 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0.625rem;
}

#photo-gallery .overview {
  align-items: center;
  background: #23282d;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#photo-gallery .overview img {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

[image: First]

## Second issue

I want to remove background of `.overview` and replace it with a blurred effect. (example: `filter: blur(5px);`)

The problem is that when I apply blurred effect on gallery that `.overview` is blurry too.

Comment: In the first problem what do you really want? You would like to display the image always 90% width or you would like to display the whole image in one screen without scrolling and the image width is affected by the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue can be solved by giving `max-height: 100%` to the `img`

```
#photo-gallery .overview img {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

see this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/YqEQxZ)**

for the second question,

> When using the blur or opacity property, it is not possible to ignore
>   the child element. If you apply either of those properties to parent
>   element, it will automatically apply to child elements too.

You have to go for alternate solutions, 
see this [How to blur(css) div without blur child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975673/how-to-blurcss-div-without-blur-child-element)