# Blur all but one element in the body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to blur everything on the screen except the loading animation. This is what I have tried.

```js
$("#addall").click(function() {
  $('#loading').show();
  $('body:not(#loading)').css("filter", "blur(3px)");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="simple-loading" style="display: none" id="loading">
  <div class="active dimmer">
    <div class="text loader">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec placerat id nisi eget egestas. <a id="addall" href="javascript:void(0)">Load.</a> Nullam luctus ac ipsum vel blandit. Cras eu felis ac lorem porta egestas. Sed interdum cursus ligula, sit amet euismod velit volutpat at. Fusce luctus scelerisque mollis. Praesent ligula neque, vehicula elementum justo sed, egestas accumsan eros. Suspendisse at est eget nunc efficitur vestibulum. Suspendisse potenti. Pellentesque quis fermentum ligula.</div>
```

Also I have tried

```
$("body").each(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id != "loading") {
        $(this).css("filter","blur(3px)");
    }
});
```

and it never works... Is there any good solution?

Comment: Try this, $('body').not("#loading").css("filter","blur(3px)");

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that your selector works on all `body` elements and then picks the ones that do not have ID `loading`. Since there is only one `body` element and it indeed does not have this ID, it is selected. Of course, this is not what you want. You want to select all *children of* the `body` element and then filter those that do not have the `loading` ID.

The selector needs to be `body > *:not(#loading)`.

To clarify: this selector selects all elements (`*`)...
...that are children of the body (`body > *`)
...and do not have ID loading (`*:not(#loading)`).

This uses the [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) ([spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#child-combinators)) and [negation pseudo-class `:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) ([spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#negation)).

```css
body > *:not(#loading) {
  background: #ffd83c;
  filter: blur(3px);
}

div, p {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Some DIV.</div>
<div id="loading">Loading DIV</div>
<div>Some other DIV.</div>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: `$('body>*:not(#loading)').css("filter","blur(3px)");` still blur everything. why?

Comment: @Pwan I tried to explain it in my answer. Is there something that I can still clarify?

Answer (score 14):

**Try This**

You can achieve this using css only. NO NEED TO JQUERY

Please see the below code

```css
body > *:not(#loading) {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div>Some DIV.</div>
<div id="loading">Loading DIV
    <div style='padding:15px;'>Some other DIV inside loading div.</div>
</div>
<div>Some other DIV.</div>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately [you cannot blur an HTML node without blurring its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975673/how-to-blurcss-div-without-blur-child-element).

One solution is to put your contents and loading image in two `div`s inside a parent `div` like the following.

```
<div id="parent_div" style="position:relative;height:300px;width:300px;">
    <div id="background" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background-color:red;filter: blur(3px);z-index:-1;"></div>
    <div id="loading">Spinner...</div>
</div>
```

To blur/unblur just do `$('#background').css('filter', 'blur(3px))`.

Comment: Other solutions describe above are good, but +1 for explaining why it doesn't work when selecting the body.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
$("#addall").click( function() {
    $('#loading').show();
    $('body').not("#loading").css("filter","blur(3px)");
});
```

I have changed, the way syntax worked.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This blurs the entire body and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still scratching their head about this, despite the answers provided. You have to start your wildcard blurring from the immediate parent to the child you want unblurred. In my case, I had to do something like this:

```
body.modal-open > #wrapper > #page-content-wrapper > #app > div > *:not(#newApplicationModal)
```

Because if I had simply done

```
body.modal-open > *:not(#newApplicationModal)
```

It still blurred everything, because the nested children of body were parent containers of my desired unblurred item, resulting in the parent being blurred and the contents blurring along with it regardless.

Answer (score 3):

### A better solution from **2023**

I'm using `backdrop-filter: blur()` instead of `filter: blur()` to make sure the elements behind the `.backdrop` are blurred, instead of the element itself.

I hope the code is self-explanatory (the complete code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nipunadodan/pen/RwByxbo)). But for those who are wondering, it's just the `.backdrop` positioned over all the elements using `position: fixed;` and `z-index:9998;`. And then the `.except` is placed over the `.backdrop` using `z-index: 9999;` which is one level higher than the `.backdrop` but only using `position: relative;` so it's at the same place as it was before.

**This way you can blur everything including the backgrounds except for the desired element and you don't need to reposition the `.except` element somewhere else this way.**

Let me know if I've missed something.

```css
.except {
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9998;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background: #33333377;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">Some text</div>  
    <div class="content except">Some text</div>  
    <div class="content">Some text</div>
    <div class="content">Some text</div> 
</div>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
```

Demo with the complete code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nipunadodan/pen/RwByxbo)

Answer (score 2):

This is simple. Try the following:

```
$('body').not("#loading").css("filter","blur(3px)");
```

The above selector is selecting the whole body except element with id loading.

However I've corrected the syntax but this wont blur except loading because everything under body will be blurred. You have to change your html structure like:

```
 <body>
    <div id="loading">Here your logic image..text or whatever</div>
    <div id="bodyContainer">Your whole html that was in your body</div>
 </body>
```

Now in jquery you can do the following:

```
 $('#bodyContainer').css("filter","blur(3px)");
```

Comment: This blurs the entire body and does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
body > *:not(#loading > *){
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```