# How to blur all elements except one with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to blur all elements except the `p#this` tag. Remember that I would like to do this in javascript. Not jQuery or CSS as I am trying to learn vanilla javascript.

On [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42827504/blur-all-but-one-element-in-the-body) I found somewhat a similar answer. @prog1011 gave an answer and I am trying to implement but it did not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgq4szte/1/

```
<h1>New Title</h1>
<h2>New Title 2</h2>
<h3>New Title 2</h3>
<p id="this">New paragraph</p>
```

JS

```
document.querySelector("body :not(#this)").style.filter = "blur(2px)";
```

How I can blur all elements except for `p#this` tag?

Answer (score 6):

Combine usage of `.querySelectorAll` and `.forEach`, because `.style` can be used on a singular node only:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("body :not(#this)")
  .forEach(element => element.style.filter = "blur(2px)");
```

```html
<h1>New Title</h1>
<h2>New Title 2</h2>
<h3>New Title 2</h3>
<p id="this">This paragraph</p>
<p id="that">That paragraph</p>
```

Comment: what if `p#this` is a child element? does this work?