# How do I clear a filter placed by a parent element in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-filters

I have a `<div>` with a background image and I'd like the background image to have a filter applied. But I'd also like the div to contain a `<p>` tag which overlays the image -- and I DONT want the `<p>` to have that same filter.

*How do I clear the filter set by the `<div>` in the `<p>`?*

What I've got so far:

```
<div className="artistDetailImage" style={{backgroundImage: url(${this.props.artistImage})`}}>
  <p className="artistDetailText">{name}</p>
</div>

.artistDetailImage {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  filter: contrast(60%);
}

.artistDetailText {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 240px;
  filter: none; //Have also tried contrast(100%), brightness(1), etc.
  color: white;
}
```

This answer seems to work, but I was hoping there was a better way to do it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32677739/3010955

Comment: you *can't* reset a filter in a *child* element in CSS...

Comment: filter is always applied to whole thing!

Comment: Ah okay, good to know. I found another SO answer that had a solution, I was just probing to see if there was a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to reset the filter for the child element, but you can encase both in a container div, then position the `<p>` accordingly.

```css
.container-div {
  position: relative;
}

.artistDetailImage {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  filter: contrast(60%);
}

.artistDetailText {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-div">
  <div class="artistDetailImage" style="background-image: url('http://static.pexels.com/photos/33688/delicate-arch-night-stars-landscape.jpg');">
  </div>
  <p class="artistDetailText">NAME</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm. What does the `position: relative` in the `container-div` do?

Comment: @PeterKaminski The position: absolute in the paragraph element will position it relative to its nearest container element that is not position: static, so we set the parent container to position: relative.