# How to disable css filter property on specific child element?

Tags: css

I cant disable this property on my child element. Is there a way to disable this property on the box?I can't move this element out of the parent.

```css
.full {
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  filter:blur(2px);
}

.box {
  border:1px solid black;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:5px;

}

.non-blur{
  filter:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="box">Blured</div>
  <div class="non-blur box">Clean</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you just apply the blur property directly to the `.box` instead of the parent?

Comment: Its just simple example,the parent container is a body element in my case.Hard to do.

Comment: this is something that is *not* possible... apply `filter` on `.box:not(.non-blur)`

Comment: You can't have a child element ignore the parent's blur. Essentially the only option is to have two divs inside the parent, one for blur and one for not-blur. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975673/how-to-blurcss-div-without-blur-child-element) page goes into it in a little more detail.

Comment: Try do this 
https://jsfiddle.net/8r68ktdk/