# How to change CSS property wchich depends of other compoentent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to do some website with react library. But to finalize that nicely I don't know how to change CSS properties wchich depends from other. For example I don't want this blur filter in my text area `.mirror-container` what is used in background `.home-header`

Here is the code:

```
.home-header {
    height: 55vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url("./assets/images/bg.jpeg") ;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter: blur(3px);
    background-position-y: 80%;
}
.mirror-container {
    width: 50rem;
    height: 85%;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0, .5);
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;  // HERE NEED TO BE WITHOUT BLUR 
}
```

Also I want to ask how to add some shadow on the end of picture. I mean something like that to make smoothly changing the backgrounds. Or maybe I should import a shadow wave png and insert it below the image? What would be the best solution?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your question about the `blur` value of the `filter` CSS property has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975673/how-to-blurcss-div-without-blur-child-element) before.

In short, `filter`, like other CSS properties such as `opacity` applies all the way down the affected DOM subtree, so you can't prevent the child element (`.mirror-container`) from being affected by the blurring effect defined in the parent element (`.home-header`).

A viable alternative would be to add an element in between the two that covers the `.home-header` element, and apply a `backdrop-filter: blur(3px)` to that element instead.

The `backdrop-filter` CSS property only applies the filter to the area *behind* the affected element, so you'll see the blurring effect over `.home-header` butl still see the content inside `.mirror-container` as expected.