# Set blur effect on container but not a specific element within

Tags: html, css, blur

How can I apply `filter: blur(20px)` to a div with class `todo`, but not the div with class `modal`?

Is it possible, perhaps with the help of SCSS?

**Code:**

```css
.todo {
  display: grid;
}

.modal {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='todo'>
  <div class='todo__sidebar'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <div class='modal'>
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/JulieJones/pen/GRqGNKR)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the modal in a container and use `backdrop-filter`:

```css
.todo {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
}

.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='todo'>
  <div class='todo__sidebar'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>

    <div class="modal-container">
      <div class='modal'>
        <span>12345</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Though, the support is [not great](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter).

---

Another option is to use JS:

```js
document.querySelector('ul').style.filter = 'blur(5px)';
```

```css
.todo {
  display: grid;
}

.modal {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='todo'>
  <div class='todo__sidebar'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class='modal'>
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or, you could swap them around in the HTML and use the sibling selector (`~`):

```css
.todo {
  display: grid;
}

.modal {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}

.modal ~ ul {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class='todo'>
  <div class='todo__sidebar'>
    <div class='modal'>
      <span>12345</span>
    </div>

    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

None of these are ideal but just some options if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "unblur" a child element of a blurred element.

> Typically, rendering an element via CSS or SVG can conceptually be described as if the element, **including its children**, are drawn into a buffer (such as a raster image) and then that buffer is composited into the elements parent.
>
> -- [Filter Effect Module Level 1](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#abstract:%7E:text=Typically%2C%20rendering%20an%20element%20via%20CSS,is%20composited%20into%20the%20elements%20parent.)

* Emphasis mine.

You will need to apply `filter` only on the element you want blurred. Checkout anwsers in [How to blur (css) div without blur child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975673/how-to-blurcss-div-without-blur-child-element) and [How to apply a CSS filter to a background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-filter-to-a-background-image).

Comment: What OP is asking can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `div` with class `modal` as a child of `todo` so that it is on top of that div. Here is the code that works:

```css
.todo {
  display: grid;
  filter: blur(20px);
}
    
.modal {
  display: grid;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='todo'>
  <div class='todo__sidebar'>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='modal'>
     <span>12345</span>
</div>
```